# Links broken for shiny quickstart

Tags: r, shiny

I'm following the R Shiny [tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) from the RStudio site and the [link to download the slides and exercises](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjt6g3ctdqvihat/shiny-quickstart-1.zip?dl=0) is broken. Perhaps someone deleted their dropbox? Does anyone know where else this content can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Material can be downloaded at https://github.com/rstudio-education/shiny.rstudio.com-tutorial